# Parsing a list of lists to a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have list of lists. Below is how my list looks like, I want to parse it into a data frame with continuation of values with columns = A,B,C

```
[     A  B  C
  0   1  2  3
  1   1  2  3
  2   1  2  3
  3   1  2  3

      A  B  C
  0   4  5  6
  1   4  5  6
  2   4  5  6
  3   4  5  6
]
```

The expected data frame is as below

```
     A  B  C
  0   1  2  3
  1   1  2  3
  2   1  2  3
  3   1  2  3
  4   4  5  6
  5   4  5  6
  6   4  5  6
  7   4  5  6
```

Really appreciate the help.

Comment: What is the type of your input ? a `string` ? The current input isn't a valid python list.

Comment: Please provide correct Python input. This is not a Python list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
list1=[]
count=0
while count<len(myList):
    list2= myList[count]
    list1.append(list2)
    #print(list2)
    count+=1
df = pd.concat(list1)
print(df)
```

`myList` : List which contains sub-lists

`list2` : First it takes sub-lists`myList[count]` then append it to `list1`

`list1` : Final list which contains all sub-lists as one separate list

`df` : Pandas DataFrame

Comment: @Legolas Is this answer helpful?